# get data rendering by controller from ajax call - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to execute a ruby script when an ajax call is made within a controller and get the result.
But I still have an error 500 from my ajax call...

**file.js**

```
$.post("/script/scraping", { "url" : url }, function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

**/script/scraping.rb**

```
puts "test"
```

**/config/routes.rb**

```
post "/scraping", :to "scraping#run_script"
```

**/app/controller/scraping_controller.rb**

```
class ScrapingController < ApplicationController
    def run_script
       @results = `ruby /script/scraping.rb`
    end
end
```

**EDIT:**

Alright, I fixed it. The problem was the rendering of /scraping path. The response threw a missing template error, then I simply add to my action

```
render :text => @results
```

Comment: You shouldn't be posting to `.rb` files by the look of your routes you want to be posting to "/scraping"

Comment: Another question. Were you a php developer before trying rails?

Comment: woops, my bad when i was writing this question. I already post to /script/scraping

Comment: Yes I do, because of using $.post instead of $.ajax?

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't be running `ruby /script/scraping` can you not call a function to do the scraping then render that?

Comment: In term of organisation, I thought it was more logic to call a scraping script. However in RoR, create a controller to routing is mandatory.. so I don't really know what is the best pratice...

Comment: Your action is post to scraping. Your view is whatever `/script/scraping.rb` returns.